# Try To Recreate An Accidentally Deleted Ubuntu System

Tags: system-installation, disk-usage, system, delete

I am new to this forum and am forced to admit how stupid I was : I managed to delete an Ubuntu VM ACCIDENTALLY.
Now I am trying to reinstall that system BUT I am also being asked to repartition my system
which is something I have never done before.
Could it be that the deletion of the original was NOT complete and there are still large areas of my disk space
allocated to Ubuntu ?

To go into more detail means talking about Windows 10, the host OS for my Ubuntu system.
I seem to have far too few G’s of disk space  left over on my system.
Then I notice that my Documents folder uses more than 20G, even though I have never manually put anything in there. So I delete Documents. Next thing I know when I try to open Ubuntu using VMWare,
the message says there is no such system. It did say it was searching in Fred/Documents ( which no longer exists ).

When I try to reinstall Ubuntu I get to screen where it insists I either repartition my system or quit the installation entirely.
What files/systems should I find and delete first on my Windows system ?

Thank You.

Comment: Let’s slow down and take this one step at a time. You’re using Ubuntu in a VM, yes? Which version of Ubuntu, and what VM software are you using?

Comment: VMWare Workstation 15 Player uses  iso :ubuntu-21.04-desktop-amd64.iso presumably for Ubuntu 21.04

Comment: In that case, the partitioning is completely safe. This will be done on a virtual disk that is read only by VMware. Your Windows partition and its data will not be touched. Install with confidence 

Comment: Now when I click on ‘New Partition Table’ it does not go beyond that. It says I have free space of 12.9G on device /dev/sda and ‘Device for boot loader installation:’ is  ‘/dev/sda VMware, VMware Virtual ( 12.9 GB )’.

However ‘Install Now’ is grayed out and the only options are ‘Revert’, ‘Quit’ or ‘Back’.

Comment: Generally it’s recommended that an Ubuntu Desktop installation be given at least 25GB of space. Minimal installs can be done on smaller devices, but it’s rather tight. As for partitioning, [let the installer handle it for you](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-allocate-drive-space). Unless you need to do something very specific, there is rarely any need to manually specify partitions.

Comment: So this time I deleted the VM ( or at least the space allocated to it ) deliberately,
first checking that VMWare would actually let me choose the exact size of any new VM.
Set it at 32G this time. On installation it now says ‘free space 34.4G’ and below that 34359M.
However the ‘Install’ button is STILL grayed out.